# How to identify a new PFRelation on AfterSave using Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to identify what has changed on a PFRelation column on the AfterSave method of a table? I want to identify an User who liked an Item. The Item table has a UserLikes PFRelation which has all users that liked that Item. I want to trigger execute a notification whenever a new User likes an Item, but only for that new User, not the ones that liked it previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is possible. However, I would instead create a cloud code function for the notification, and then trigger that in the `afterSave` block for the *like*. If the like was successfully saved, notify the owner of the liked item.

If that doesn't work with your current data model, take a look at how Parse solves liking in the Anypic tutorial app.